# How to correctly render points in SceneKit with colours including alpha values?

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, metal

I am trying to render a collection of points in SceneKit all of which have an alpha value less than 1 as part of their colour. While this seems to work, it depends on the angle at which you are looking at the point.

My current method has been to create an array of vertices with corresponding colours and indices, wrap these up inside SCNGeometrySource/SCNGeometryElement and create a custom SCNGeometry from theses. The SCNGeometryElement for the indices is set to render as points. Some sample code below of how I'm setting this up.

```swift
var vertices = [SCNVector3]()
var colors = [float4]()
var indices = [UInt32]()

for x in 0...10 {
    for y in 0...10 {
        for z in 0...10 {
            vertices.append(SCNVector3(x - 5, y - 5, z - 5))
            colors.append(float4(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1))
            indices.append(UInt32(vertices.count - 1))
        }
    }
}

let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

let colorsData = Data(bytes: &colors, count: colors.count * MemoryLayout<float4>.stride)
let colorSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: colorsData, semantic: .color, vectorCount: colors.count, usesFloatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 4, bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride, dataOffset: 0, dataStride: MemoryLayout<float4>.stride)

let pointsElement = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .point)
pointsElement.pointSize = 0.2
pointsElement.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 1
pointsElement.maximumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 50

let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, colorSource], elements: [pointsElement])
let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

When my camera node is located as follow, everything looks good:

```
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, 0.5 * CGFloat.pi, 0)
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 10, y: 0, z: 0)
```

[image: Expected rendering]

However if I move my camera to the next face of the cube clockwise the alpha no longer renders:

```
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -0.5 * CGFloat.pi, 0)
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -10, y: 0, z: 0)
```

[image: Undesired rendering]

Placing the camera half way gives a combination of the two:

```
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
```

[image: Semi-expected rendering]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, SceneKit doesn’t allow you to specify that you’d like point primitives reordered for correct compositing within a single geometry. You might need to run a compute shader or a CPU-side sort to reorder the points in view space.

Comment: Thanks @warrenm that's useful to know. What order should I be sorting the vertices in then? Presumably I need to do this any time the camera moves or the geometry rotates?

Comment: Actually, before we go there, have you tried setting the `writesToDepthBuffer` property of the geometry's material to `false`?

Comment: If you draw this semitransparent field after any opaque geometry and use a suitable blending mode, you might get the effect you want without sorting.

Comment: Perfect @warrenm it works! I'd tried out `isDoubleSided` and `transparencyMode` but had forgotten about the depth buffer. Would you like to submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?